# how to include jQuery library in wordpress plugin correctly?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

in my code I wrote so

```
wp_enqueue_script('cwp-main-datepicker', plugins_url('/Scripts/jquery.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core'));
```

but they said that its not correct way to call jQuery library, they say that wordpress has  own jquery libraries but I don't know which library  call and how?? Please help me somebody....

Comment: Note the array at the end, that will include jQuery and jQuery UI for you automatically, so you don't need to add it yourself. Use that same array when you include your custom javascript that requires jQuery, and it will work.

Comment: it works, but they want that i include wordpress's jquery library... I don't know which library call and how?

Comment: Who wants you to include jQuery, and why? There's must be a file that requires jQuery, and that's where you add the dependency, and jQuery will be loaded automagically for you.

Comment: wordpress administartion wants..  I dont know why..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include the `jquery` library already provided by WordPress as follows :

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

Hope it helps you.